# How to tell Chrome or Safari to display a page with certain encoding?

Tags: html, google-chrome, character-encoding, safari

I was accessing this page: http://protege.stanford.edu/publications/ontology_development/ontology101-noy-mcguinness.html when I saw that my browsers (Safari and Chrome) don't display some characters properly (Prot�g� when it's supposed to be Protégé).

I think it's because the content was not sent with UTF-8 encoding, but Chrome and Safari default to UTF-8 when the encoding is not mentioned in the HTML page (in `<meta>` tag).

I tried saving the page through Safari (it doesn't work through Chrome) in Sublime Text 2 and tell it to "Save with Encoding" UTF-8, and I can see that it's displaying correctly, but I don't know the original encoding used.

Obviously I don't have control on that website, and so I cannot change the content send. So I think I need to tell my browser to use specific encoding used when the server encoded that page.

So I have two questions:

1. What encoding is used on that page to display the page properly?
2. How can I tell Chrome or Safari to use that encoding?

Comment: w3c validator says it's utf-8 but later throws an error that it couldn't validate the document because some characters are not unicode

Answer (score 1):

**New Answer**

I apologize for my hasty answer.

In Chrome, you can override the encoding by going to Menu > More Tools > Encoding. I tested the page you linked to with "Western (Windows 1252)" and it looked just fine after that.

Here's a useful link to this end: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95290?hl=en

**Old answer**

You have to declare the encoding for the page. See: http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/web/tips/declare.html

Comment: But it's not my website. I do not have control over its content.

Comment: Apologies. I revised my answer.